# Plot x against y Statsmodels mixed-model result

Tags: python, matplotlib, statsmodels, mixed-models

I want to plot my Statsmodels mixed-model result with X against Y, and would like some verification that I've understood it correctly. I am mostly uncertain how I should treat the fixed parameters (`other_fixed_effects` in the code segment), and if they should be included.

Fixed parameters:

```
Intercept            330.777402
Score                 39.101520
Group Var              8.264719
Group x Score Cov      0.248543
Score Var              0.007475
dtype: float64
```

My code:

```python
# Load data from fitted model
parameters = final_volume_fit.params
r_effects = final_volume_fit.random_effects

# Fig size
fig = plt.figure(figsize = (16, 9))

# Fixed effects
fixed_intercept = parameters[0]
fixed_score = parameters[1]
fixed_grp_var = parameters[2]
fixed_grpxscore_var = parameters[3]
fixed_score_var = parameters[4]

# Color counter
ctr = 0

# Group represent the different stocks, j=(AAPL,...,VIAC)
for group in r_effects:
    
    # Random effects, intercept and slope
    group_intercept = r_effects[group][0]
    group_slope = r_effects[group][1]
    
    # Random and fixed effects added togheter 
    # (Fixed intercept + Intercept(j))
    y_group_intercept = fixed_intercept+group_intercept
    
    # (Fixed slope + slope(j))
    y_group_slope = fixed_score+group_slope
    
    
    # Observed traded volume for the timeperiod
    z = corrected_data_transformed.loc[corrected_data_transformed['Stock'] == group]     
    stock_dates = list(z['Date'])
    stock_volume = list(z['Transformed_Volume']) 
    
    stock_line = []
    # Stock dates represents the timeperiod, i=(1,...,15), that observations was carried out during.
    for i in stock_dates:
        
        # Data point for regressionline
        data_point = y_group_intercept + y_group_slope*i
        
        #Should these fixed effects (other_fixed_effects) also be added to the estimation of data_point?
        other_fixed_effects = fixed_grp_var*i + fixed_grpxscore_var*i + fixed_score_var*i
        
        observation_ij = data_point + other_fixed_effects
        
        # Add estimation to regressionline
        stock_line.append(observation_ij)
        
    
    # Seaborn plot ax
    ax = sns.lineplot(x = stock_line, y = stock_volume ,
                      color = colors[ctr], label = group)
    
    # Increase color counter
    ctr += 1
    
# Plot settings
ax.set(xlabel='Regressionline', ylabel='Volume')
ax.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(0, 1), loc=2, borderaxespad=0.1)
ax.figsize = (16, 9)
ax.set_title('Regression-line for each observation X against registered volume during timeperiod Y', weight='bold').set_fontsize('16')

picture = plt.savefig('yijplot2.png', bbox_inches='tight')
plt.show()
```

Below is my plot:
[image: plotxagainsty]

Answer (score 0):

Any parameter whose name ends in "Var" or "Cov" is describing the variance structure, not the mean structure.  These terms should not be added to this type of plot in the way that you have done (they are already accounted for in the internal calculation of the BLUPs for the random effects).

Originally I though you were planning to plot the fitted y against x=score.  In that case the plot should contain a line for each stock, not a non-linear path.  You are plotting the fitted values on the horizontal axis (which is unusual), and I'm not clear about what you are putting on the vertical axis.